# CodeIgniter foreach loops return value issue

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I am stuck with CodeIgniter loop & arrays, I want to get each username & pid time.

```
    function UserStat()
    {       
        $this->db->select('username');      
        $this->db->where('status=','1');
        $query=$this->db->get("user_id");
        $uname=$query->result_array();
        
        foreach($uname as $name)
        {
            $this->db->select('SUM(pid) AS `UserTotalPid`');
            $this->db->like('user',$name['username']);
            $UsrTotalPidInSec['UserTotalPid']=$this->db->get('user_data')->row()->UserTotalPid;
            $data[]['username']=$name['username'];
            $data[]['UsrTotalPidInMin']=floor($UsrTotalPidInSec['UserTotalPid']/60).':'.gmdate('s',$UsrTotalPidInSec['UserTotalPid']);
        
        }
        return $data;
        //print_r($data);
    }
}
```

**I am getting now this return this**

return output: `[{"username":"Michle"},{"UsrTotalPidInMin":"1:58"},{"username":"Docker"},{"UsrTotalPidInMin":"0:55"},{"username":"Marchel"},{"UsrTotalPidInMin":"2:34"}]`

print_r Output: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => Michle ) [1] => Array ( [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 1:58 ) [2] => Array ( [username] => Docker ) [3] => Array ( [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 0:55 ) [4] => Array ( [username] => Marchel ) [5] => Array ( [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 2:34 ) )`

**If I put return or print array inside of loop I am getting this**

return output: `[{"username":"Michle"},{"UsrTotalPidInMin":"1:58"}]`

print_r output: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => Michle ) [1] => Array ( [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 1:58 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => Michle ) [1] => Array ( [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 1:58 ) [2] => Array ( [username] => Docker ) [3] => Array ( [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 0:55 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => Michle ) [1] => Array ( [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 1:58 ) [2] => Array ( [username] => Docker ) [3] => Array ( [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 0:55 ) [4] => Array ( [username] => Marchel ) [5] => Array ( [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 2:34 ) )`

**But my exception is like this**

return output: `[{"username":"Michle","UsrTotalPidInMin":"1:58"},{"username":"Docker","UsrTotalPidInMin":"0:55"},{"username":"Marchel","UsrTotalPidInMin":"2:34"}]`

print_r output: `Array ( [username] => Michle [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 1:58 ) Array ( [username] => Docker [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 0:55 ) Array ( [username] => Marchel [UsrTotalPidInMin] => 2:34 )`

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing your actual and expected results. That helps a lot.

To address your array issue, you can change this section...

```
$data[]['username']=$name['username'];
$data[]['UsrTotalPidInMin']=floor($UsrTotalPidInSec['UserTotalPid']/60).':'.gmdate('s',$UsrTotalPidInSec['UserTotalPid']);
```

To something like...

```
$UsrTotalPidInMin = floor($UsrTotalPidInSec['UserTotalPid']/60).':'.gmdate('s',$UsrTotalPidInSec['UserTotalPid']);
$data[] = array('username'=>$name['username'],'UsrTotalPidInMin'=>$UsrTotalPidInMin);
```

In the above, I have taken out $UsrTotalPidInMin as a separate statement to make the $data[] statement easier to read.

Comment: TimBrownlaw Thanks a lot, You are really lifesaver, its working fine but its seems little slow to get info from db, what do you think, it could be for code? or do I have to change anything in the code to make it more fast. Thanks ones again.

Comment: Yes, I'd be looking at reducing the need to perform a DB query on each loop. If you could add a brief description of your user_info Table with some example data  in your question, that might help. Your user_id table is pretty basic.

Comment: If my answer was correct / helped can you mark it as such! And make your "speed" question a new question with the information I suggested above.